# How to drop row which contains "no comment" string in column?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

How can I drop all rows in `.csv` file, that contains the field `category` string = "no comment"?

This is my `.csv` file:

[image: csv file]

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please dont uplaod images. Use **text** only.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `str.contains`:

```
df = df.drop(df['category'].str.contains('no comment'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The below seems to work

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'num':7,'category':'something'},{'num':79,'category':'no comment'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.drop(df[df.category == 'no comment'].index)
print(df)
```

output

```
    category  num
0  something    7
```

Comment: @Corralien - just did :-)

Comment: Thank you very much!